# Create process as user in ruby

Tags: windows, ruby, security

The following code is in a file called run.rb, the idea is to run ruby as a different user so I can do some testing.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'win32/process'

domain = 'WORLDWIDE'
user_name = 'user'
password = 'password'
rubyScript = 'ruby test.rb'
Process.create(:command_line => rubyScript, :domain => domain, :with_logon => user_name, :password => password, :close_handles => false)
```

the contents of test.rb is:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir'

browser = Watir::IE.new
browser.goto('http://localhost:44001/Users/List')
puts browser.text
```

when I run 'ruby run.rb'  a command shell opens and then closes straight away.
Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I added the Windows tag as it limits some of your options. On Unix rig this could be accomplished with sudo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reviving a dead question, but in Windows NT, other users can't interact with your desktop. So if you're logged on as `DOMAIN\user1` and spawn a process as `DOMAIN\user2`, the `DOMAIN\user2` process cannot interact with `DOMAIN\user1`'s desktop. An exception to this is if the process is running as a service and has the "Can interact with desktop" box checked in the service properties (but I think that requires that it run as `SYSTEM`).

It is possible to use the Local Security Policy (secpol.msc) to assign user rights to that user that permits that user to interact with everyone's desktops, but that would be unsafe to do if the user is granted the right to logon interactively.

Comment: I marked this as correct as it is probably the right answer - however I am way past working on that problems so won't be trying it out right now :)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably running your command just fine, opening a new command window (since it's a new windows Process), then closing that window when it completes. Try throwing a "sleep 1000" at the end of test.rb. If I'm correct, that *should* keep the window around so that you can view the output.

Comment: Putting in the sleep has no effect.
If the code had have run, it would have opened an IE instance which I probably would have noticed :)